# Wagmi how to catch and display MetaMask errors?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, metamask, wagmi

I am using `wagmi` to connect to MetaMask wallet to get some information and I noticed that I can get 2 errors.

One error is `ConnectorNotFoundError: Connector not found at MetaMaskConnector.connect...` if I don't have the MetaMask extension installed.
The other error is `{code: -32002, message: 'Already processing eth_requestAccounts. Please wait.'}` is the connecting process that is started is not finished.

How can I check for those errors and display their message or a custom one?

I used `connect` from wagmi hook `useConnect` and I tried to use a `try-catch` block but it did not catch the errors. Also, the `useConnect` hook comes with `error` but if I console log the `error` it comes as `null`, even if I get any of the 2 errors.

```
  const { connect, error } = useConnect({
    connector: MetaMask,
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(error)
    try {
      connect();
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.error('Error connecting:', err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useConnect#onerror-optional

Answer (score 0):

try catch is not working in the case, you should try put call back function `onError` into the `useConnect` hook.

```
const { connect, connectors, error, isLoading, pendingConnector } = useConnect({
        onSuccess(data, variables, context) {
            const { account, chain } = data;
        },
        onError(error, variables, context) {
            console.log('error', { error, variables, context });
            if (variables.connector.id === 'metaMask') {
                setErrorMsg('An unexpected error occurred.');
            }
        },
    });
```